# Container instances not being registered from capacity provider

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I created an ECS cluster with an Auto Scaling Group capacity provider. The capacity provider shows that there are 2 instances (t2.micro) launched (but they are not listed in the container instances).
[image: capacity provider has instances]

I created one (and only) service in the ECS cluster.
Task definition:

```json
{
    "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:ap-south-1:<acc_id>:task-definition/basic-iris-app-td:3",
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "name": "basic-iris-app",
            "image": "<acc_id>.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/basic-iris-app:latest",
            "cpu": 0,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "name": "8080",
                    "containerPort": 8080,
                    "hostPort": 8080,
                    "protocol": "tcp",
                    "appProtocol": "http"
                }
            ],
            "essential": true,
            "environment": [],
            "environmentFiles": [],
            "mountPoints": [],
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "ulimits": [],
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-create-group": "true",
                    "awslogs-group": "/ecs/basic-iris-app-td",
                    "awslogs-region": "ap-south-1",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
                },
                "secretOptions": []
            }
        }
    ],
    "family": "basic-iris-app-td",
    "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::<acc_id>:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
    "networkMode": "awsvpc",
    "revision": 3,
    "volumes": [],
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "requiresAttributes": [
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.awslogs"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-awslogs"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.ecr-auth"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.19"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-ecr-pull"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.18"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.task-eni"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.29"
        }
    ],
    "placementConstraints": [],
    "compatibilities": [
        "EC2"
    ],
    "requiresCompatibilities": [
        "EC2"
    ],
    "cpu": "205",
    "memory": "205",
    "runtimePlatform": {
        "cpuArchitecture": "X86_64",
        "operatingSystemFamily": "LINUX"
    },
    "registeredAt": "2024-01-17T10:20:50.700Z",
    "registeredBy": "arn:aws:iam::<acc_id>:root",
    "tags": []
}
```

The service does not start and fails with an error saying `Capacity provider is empty`.
[image: Task failure]

I am not able to understand why this is happening and how to fix this.

If required, [this](https://github.com/BBloggsbott/basic-iris-app) is the application I am trying to deploy.

Please let me know if I need to add more info.

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71697240/10715700) by adding it to the user data in the ASG's launch template and it did not work.

Comment: did you figure out the reason? facing same issue at the moment

Comment: although in your case it could be caused by `"hostPort"` not being zero, in your task definition. try setting it to zero

Comment: Why does it have to be zero? @mangusta

Comment: to be able to run multiple tasks on a single instance. that way, load balancer can assign hostports dynamically. see: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/dynamic-port-mapping-ecs